# Different values for the Normal ordering

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, wick-theorem

I've come across 2 examples approaching the ordering of $a^2({a^\dagger})^2$, each reach different results:

1. $a^2({a^\dagger})^2=\;:\!\sum\text{all contractions}\!:\;=\;:\!aaa^\dagger a^\dagger\!:+\;4:\!aa^\dagger\!:+\;2:\!0\!:$
2. $a^2({a^\dagger})^2=a(aa^\dagger)a^\dagger=a(a^\dagger a+1)a^\dagger=(aa^\dagger)(aa^\dagger)+aa^\dagger=(a^\dagger a+1)(a^\dagger a+1)+(a^\dagger a+1)=a^\dagger aa^\dagger a+3a^\dagger a +2=a^\dagger(a^\dagger a+1)a+3a^\dagger a +2=({a^\dagger})^2a^2+4a^\dagger a+2$

Both are Wick ordering the string but one returns an additional $+2$ term, which is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In [Wick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem) what remains in the fully contracted term (= the double contration) is the unit-operator $\hat{\bf 1}$ not the zero-operator $\hat{\bf 0}$, so OP's 1st calculation (v3) is wrong.